# Angular 2 expression single quote escape

Tags: angular

I'm using Angular 2 and I would like to write something like this

```
*ngIf="game.Championship == 'Coupe d'Alsace'"
```

However I get an error because of the single quote between d and A. Is is possible to somehow escape this character?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Usually a `\\`

```
*ngIf="game.Championship == 'Coupe d\'Alsace'"
```

or

```
*ngIf="game.Championship == 'Coupe d\\'Alsace'"
```

depending on where you put it.

Comment: Two are needed actually. Not sure why. http://plnkr.co/edit/1PuCrkfy4rrPeJh2HSpB?p=preview

Comment: Thanks for the hint. This is to get the `\` into the string literally that later gets parsed and iterpreted again.

Comment: Yes, that's what I suspected. So in an externalized HTML template, one should be sufficient.

Comment: Thanks a lot, as I use an externalized HTML is used *ngIf="game.Championship == 'Coupe d\'Alsace'"

Comment: Thanks for the answer. This answer solved my issue.