# Typescript escaping single quotes in single quotes in double quotes

Tags: google-maps, angular, typescript

I have the following code (I *think* its how I'd hack adding icon resizing to this particular Angular2/GMaps library, but that's beside the point now).

```
 <sebm-google-map-marker [latitude]="45.342" [longitude]="-122.093" [label]="''"  
   [iconUrl]="'{
      url: require('https://maps.google.com/mapfiles/kml/shapes/rail.png'), 
      scaledSize: {
        height: 20,
        width: 20
      }
}'">
     </sebm-google-map-marker>
```

The error in my browser console is

> Error: Template parse errors: Parser Error: Unexpected token 'https'
>   at column 24 in ['{ url:
>   require('https://maps.google.com/mapfiles/kml/shapes/rail.png'), /

How do I escape those inner single quotes? Thanks.

Comment: Seems like this is a duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39912555/angular-2-expression-single-quote-escape

Comment: No, the recommended answer is not working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I searched in iconUrl in its GitHub but it is just expecting a URL string. Not the object you put in template. I am not sure where you got the example and it does not look right.

Search iconUrl: https://github.com/SebastianM/angular-google-maps/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=iconUrl&type=

Cannot find anything of scaledSize: https://github.com/SebastianM/angular-google-maps/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=scaledSize&type=

Try this:

```
[iconUrl]="{
      url: 'https://maps.google.com/mapfiles/kml/shapes/rail.png', 
      scaledSize: {
        height: 20,
        width: 20
      }
}"
```

Comment: I got it from here https://github.com/SebastianM/angular-google-maps/issues/517#issuecomment-260210284 There seem to be many subtle indications that people have solved this problem for this library,but no one has explicitly said "This is how you do it", other than reading closely and seeing the thumbs up of the comment.

Comment: See my updated code, let me know if it works. Basically, remove the beginning and ending single quote. Don't use [] binding, just pass the string in.

Comment: Ah, I got it to work! All I had to do was 1. Add the [] around iconUrl, and remove the require (the browser console was giving me an error there). TY!